# NServiceBus and Windsor Installer

Tags: castle-windsor, nservicebus, asp.net-web-api, cqrs

I have a CQRS architecture that is all plugged using Windsor and Windsor Installers. Problem occurs now when we are plugging in NServiceBus.

Right now we have a Command Handler with the following signature

```
public class MyCommandHandler : Handles<MyCommand>
{
   public MyCommandHandler(IDomainEvents events)
   {
       /// bla bla
       events.Raise<MyEvent>();
   }
}
```

I want to change this by injecting IBus and have the following code implementation

```
public class MyCommandHandler : Handles<MyCommand>
{
   public MyCommandHandler(IBus bus)
   {
       /// bla bla
       bus.Send("MyQueue", myMessage);
   }
}
```

So in order to do this I need to create an NServiceBus Client Windsor Installer and bootstrap the Client bus from Windsor. I though to do something like this

```
public class BusClientInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
{
   public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
   {
      IBus bus = ConfigureBus();
      container.Register(Component.For<IBus>().Instance(bus));
   }
}
```

And I configure my bus in the method below

```
  var busConfiguration = new BusConfiguration();
  /// configuration
  var bus = Bus.Create(busConfiguration);
  return bus;
```

Is this the correct approach? Should I use a Factory that create a new instance of the bus for each Handler or is ok to have a SingleTon bus instance? The handlers are executed within a Web API controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're using NServiceBus version 5?  The configuration code changed since version 4.x, so I'm not as familiar with it, but the basic principle is the same: pass an instance of your container to the code that configures the bus, and let NServiceBus handle its own registration.

From the [docs](http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/containers):

```
// Castle with a container instance
configuration.UseContainer<WindsorBuilder>(c => c.ExistingContainer(windsorContainer));
```

This will register the bus and all NServiceBus handlers in your container (no need to register any of this manually).

Comment: Do I still need to start the Bus after the registration?

Comment: Yes, the step shown above is part of creating the configuration, which gets passed to Bus.Create.  Again, I am assuming you are using 5.x.

Comment: Yes it works and yes I am working on version 5
Actually all the docs on NServiceBus referes to 4 API syntax which is quite different, plus they declared all Fluent API obsolete so we can't even compile using 5 with the old syntax.
Btw it works, thank you!

Comment: Np!  NSB 5.x came out very recently, so they are still in the process of updating the documentation.